# Vertex Specification Best Practices using OpenGL (Windows)

Tags: opengl, glsl

I wonder what is the best practice concerning cache management of the vertices.

Actually, I read numerous of articles on this topic but I'm not convinced yet by the best choice I should use.

I'm coding a small 3D rendering engine and my goal is to optimize this rendering by limiting the number of draw calls and of course the number of buffer bindings!

Until here, I gather within a single batch all the vertices of the objects sharing the same material properties (same lighting model properties and texture). if a VBO reallocation fails (GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY), then I create a new VBO to store the vertices of my object. Finally, I attach each batch to a VAO.

Pseudo-code:

```
for_each vbo in vbo_list
{
    vbo->Bind();

    for_each batch in vbo->getAttachedBatchList()
    {
        batch->BindVAO();
        {
             glDrawXXX(batch->GetOffset(), batch->GetLength());
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works well but is the technique I use is the most efficient one ?

I took a look to the following article (OpenGL ES - Mac):
    https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/TechniquesforWorkingwithVertexData/TechniquesforWorkingwithVertexData.html

This article advise to store *Interleaved Vertex Data* like below (for 3 given vertices):

```
VNTVNTVNT
```

In my case I use the following pattern:

```
VVVNNNTTT
```

Another article on the subject: https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification_Best_Practices

According to you, what is the best choice in my case ?

And finally I have another interrogation according to vertex data alignement (the topic is covered into the first article). It said "Avoid Misaligned Vertex Data". Apparently, the advise is only relevant for the case *VNTVNTVNT*.

For example, if this case is the best choice the following structure declaration should be correct:

```
struct Vertex
{
     float x, y, z;    //12 bytes
     float nx, ny, nz; //12 bytes
     float s, t;       //8 bytes
};
```

In the case sizeof(Vertex) = 32 bytes which a multiple of 4 bytes!

If I add the color components r, g, b:

```
struct Vertex
{
     float x, y, z;    //12 bytes
     float nx, ny, nz; //12 bytes
     float r, g, b;    //12 bytes
     float s, t;       //8 bytes
};
```

We've now 44 bytes which also a multiple of 4 bytes!

So according to the article, if I store my data this way it shouldn't have this misaligned data problem.

In conclusion: is my pseudo-code is correct ? Is it correct to wait a GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY exception to create a new VBO? Is it better to respect a maximum size of allocation ? And finally which is the best way to store the data (Interleaved or not) and is my data alignment proposition is correct?

**UPDATE:**

It said on the second article: `"1MB to 4MB is a nice size according to one nVidia document". It seems to be too small! I wonder if there is a mistake because I know it's possible to store a much larger amount of data (much more than 100 Mo whithout any problem on current hardware). Plus, some famous models like the Dragon could not be stored on a single VBO (it would mean that the geometry of this mesh should be shared between 4 to 5 VBOs in the best case, so 5 draw calls to render it. I can't imagine, in this case, the number of VBO allocated in real video game scene!). What do you think of that ?

[image]

Comment: 3-component floating-point vectors are GPU unfriendly. It's not the size of the structure as a whole you should be most concerned with (that sort of falls into place if you address what I'm about to discuss). Rather the boundary that each attribute begins on is important. It should be a power-of-two multiple of the size of the data type, and 12 bytes (3 * sizeof float) is not. 1,2 and 4-component vectors are fine, but 3-component should be padded out to 4.

Comment: OK. I already applied this behaviour (vec4 alignment) to store my material properties within uniform buffers but I thought it was not the case concerning vertex buffers data alignment. So, for you the 'Interleaved vertex data storage' solution is the best one ? I should store my vertices as follow: [x][y][z][0][nx][ny][nz][0][r][g][b][0][s][t][0][0][x]...Is it correct ? Thanks

Comment: I think it's better this way (according to "1,2 and 4-component vectors are fine"): [x1][y1][z1][0][nx1][ny1][nz1][0][r1][g1][b1][0][s1][t1] [x2][y2][z2]... So 3 vec4 (position, normal, color) + 1 vec2 for texture coordinates.

Comment: It applies to uniform buffers as well, but all memory generally works best if when you go to fetch 3 floating-point parameters, it's aligned to a 16-byte boundary. There are special 3-component fp data types that are 4-bytes and you can even use those for vertex attributes on some systems. If you were to spread out what you just described though, you've got successive instances of your struct beginning on a bad boundary. You could pack s and t into the 4th component of some of those attributes, I don't see much attention paid to this these days, most of your workload is per-pixel now.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for all;your explanations! Bye!